# Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs

In `package.json` file `react-router-dom` dependencies added. `App` component wrapped by `BrowswerRouter`, but when I wrap route by switch it says the following error `'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'`.  I deleted the `package-lock.json`, `node_modules/`, installed npm again and `npm install @babel/core --save`. Still not working. why it's not importing?

index.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
 import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    alert('mounting');
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    alert('updated');
  }
 render(){
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
     
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
 
  </div>
 
);
 }
}

export default App;

import React from 'react';

    const Home = () => {
    return <h1>Home</h1>;
  };
  
  export default Home;
```

package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 229, accepted):

#### Using `Routes` instead of `Switch` in react-router v6

You are using `react-router-dom` version 6, which [replaced Switch with the Routes component](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes)

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes, // instead of "Switch"
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

// ...

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Note that you now also pass your component as the `element` prop instead of using children.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this too, why is this showing Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Comment: I updated my awnser, I overlooked your react-router version, which is v6 and not v5.
Try the new fix :)

Comment: Brother Routes don't show error but it doesn't render the home component

Comment: Check the documentation link. v6 also changed the way you pass the component.
`<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />` should be correct

Comment: Just comment here, in case you are having problem with `exact`, you don't need it anymore, check: [Property 'exact' does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866581/property-exact-does-not-exist-on-type) for more details

Answer (score 18):

if you want to use `Switch` then install react-router-dom version 5. Switch is replaced in react-router-dom version 6.

```
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

Answer (score 4):

Users will not be able to find Switch in `react-router-dom`. They need to install versions up to 5 or below 5. Try the below one, which will work. If the user uses routes instead of Switch, it may not work.

```
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using react-router@v6 which uses "Routes" instead of Switch.
solution:
-Replace "Switch" with "Routes"
or
-Downgrade your react-router to v5 using
npm install react-router-dom@5

check https://reactrouter.com/en/6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: Here's an updated link: https://reactrouter.com/en/6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Answer (score 0):

Use Routes instead Switch. Switch no longer in react-router

Answer (score 0):

in case it didn't work, I've been facing the same problem with a school project of mine, and I had to work with the version 6 of react router dom, therefore the solution was for each  you should surround it with a  tag instead of putting all your  tags in a single  tag. example from my own project:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <div className="App">
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />} />
          </Routes>
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Header />} />
          </Routes>
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<About />} />
          </Routes>
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Contact />} />
          </Routes>
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/Signup" element={<Signup />} />
          </Routes>
      </div>
  )
}
```

//this will only work if you already run: npm install react-router-dom@6

Answer (score 0):

first do

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

followed by

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

P.S. I faced it myself in my production and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I've also run into this error, somehow my React import was removed. So maybe you just have to see if you have imported react or not.

Comment: As others already stated, the most common reason for this issue is that react router 6 does no longer export this class

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32204260)