# Property 'exact' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to use `react-router-dom` inside my react app and also I am using typescript instead of javascript. The issue here is that I can't import Route inside my component and make it work. I already installed `@types/react-router-dom` but for some reason it's still not working as expected.

This is a component that is trying to use `react-router-dom`

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" exact/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

And this is the error that I am getting

```
TypeScript error in /Users/veselinkontic/Projects/givellet/frontend/src/components/index.tsx(9,37):
Type '{ path: string; exact: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.
  Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.  TS2322

     7 |             <Router>
     8 |                 <div>
  >  9 |                     <Route path="/" exact/>
       |                                     ^
    10 |                 </div>
    11 |             </Router>
    12 |         </div>
```

And this is my package.json file in which you can see that everything is there.

```
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 276, accepted):

react router v6 doesn't support `exact` anymore.

// old - v5
`<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

// new - v6
`<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />`

As stated in their documentation:

> You don't need to use an exact prop on `<Route path="/">` anymore.
> This is because all  paths match exactly by default. If you
> want to match more of the URL because you have child routes use a trailing * as
> in `<Route path="users/*">`.

You can refer to this migration guide: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Also, kind of frustrating to see such drastic breaking changes without more of a timeline to migrate between v5 and v6. Literally hundreds of files for some folks.

Answer (score 13):

In the case of React Router v6, I add Routes and Route to the import.

Example:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes  } from 'react-router-dom';
import  Home  from "./pages/Home";
import  NewRoom  from "./pages/NewRoom";
    
function App() {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/"  element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path="/rooms/new" element={<NewRoom />}/>
      </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
    
export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been through this same issue, the new React-Router doesn't support the `exact` keyword. You can simply remove it from the <Route .../> and it will work just fine.

Also instead of `component` you have to use `element` and pass the element tag into it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this keeps happening to you.

But there you have:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
  ...
  "react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
  ...
},
```

And maybe the problem is that the version of your react-router-dom and the types are not the same and give compatibility problems. This library has not been updated yet. The same thing happened to me with a project that I just started.

To solve this problem, you can downgrade the version of your react-router-dom to v5 and work under that syntax, or wait for the update of the types and use the most recent version. Keep in mind that there are important changes in v6 and updating when you have a lot of code could be complicated.

Likewise, the previous answers are correct, `exact` does not exist in the new v6 of `react-router`.

Here you can see the current version of the types:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router-dom

Comment: It's not that the type library hasn't been updated; as of v6, react-router-dom includes its own type declarations and the @types package is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `exact` with `end`.

> Rename `<NavLink exact>` to `<NavLink end>`.
> https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#rename-navlink-exact-to-navlink-end

Answer (score -2):

what worked for me was re-installing the package `npm install react-router-dom`

Comment: The question is: How did you even start creating routes or facing the problem without the any router component installed ?