# Route is not working after upgrading to react-route v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I had this `MainRouting.js` component:

```
import routes from '../Routes.js';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from '../Panel/NotFound';

const MainRouting = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            {
                routes.map(route =>
                    <Route
                        key={route.path}
                        path={route.path}
                        exact
                        element={route.component} />)
            }
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default MainRouting;
```

It was working just fine. But now it's not working anymore after I upgraded to react-router v6.

I see this error:

> index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
> at Routes
> at MainRouting
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at Panel
> at LocalizationProvider
> at Router
> at BrowserRouter

How can I fix this?

Note: I already updated **NotFound** to match new syntax.

Comment: You should show us what `route.component` is. Probably you need to call the function `route.component()`. Then rr6 introduces some changes. Check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866581/property-exact-does-not-exist-on-type/69866593#69866593

Comment: @AntonioPantano, that did it. `route.component()`. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I had to do this:

```
        <Routes>
            {
                routes.map(route => {
                    const Component = route.component;
                    return <Route
                        key={route.path}
                        path={route.path}
                        element={<Component />}
                    />
                })
            }
            <Route
                path='*'
                element={<NotFound />}
            />
        </Routes>
```

The key was these lines:

```
const Component = route.component;
```

And

```
element={<Component />}
```