# I am having trouble using the EXACT property for my routes, I am using React 18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am having trouble using the EXACT property for my routes, I am using React 18

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from './pages/Landing'
import FanbaseMap from './pages/FanbaseMap'

function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Landing />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/map">
        <FanbaseMap />
      </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

> Type '{ children: Element; exact: true; path: string; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'.   Property
> 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PathRouteProps'.

I need to create routes that direct to an exact page using React and react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom@6` `Route` components have no `exact` prop. In fact, in RRDv6 routes and now ***always*** exactly matched using a [route ranking](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#ranking-routes) score.

1. Correctly render the [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route) components into the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component. `Routes` is the spiritual successor to the RRDv4/5 `Switch` component and handles the route matching logic.
2. Correctly render the routed content on the `Route` component's [`element`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#elementcomponent) prop. All route content is on the `element` prop. Only other `Route` components are valid children in the case of nested routes.
3. Remove the `exact` prop since it does nothing.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from './pages/Landing'
import FanbaseMap from './pages/FanbaseMap'

function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route path="/map" element={<FanbaseMap />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check version on react-router. React router v6 doesn't support exact anymore.
Here is detailed answer:
[Property 'exact' does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866581/property-exact-does-not-exist-on-type)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).