# React router v6 children routes not displaying correct component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got a project using `react-router` v6.

I have this code:

```
<Route exact path="planning" element={<PageNotFound />}>
  <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
  <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
</Route>
```

Which is not working at all.
When I visit `"/planning/individual"` it fallbacks on the `PageNotFound` component. It is the same for `"/planning/team"` path.

Referring to this feed: [Property 'exact' does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866581/property-exact-does-not-exist-on-type)

Even when I don't use `exact` prop it is the same behavior.
The only solution I have would be to use 2 different routes without children, but I'd rather not do this.

**EDIT**

Using:

```
<Route path="planning/*" element={<PageNotFound />}>
  <Route index element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
  <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />}
  <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
</Route>
```

This displays only `PageNotFound` on every routes starting with `"/planning"`

**EDIT 2**:

These are the complete routes:

```
<Routes>
  {!isLogged() ? (
    <>
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={"/login"} />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Navigate to={"/"} />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />

      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />

      <Route path="planning/*" element={<PageNotFound />}>
        <Route index element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
        <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />}
        <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
      </Route>
    </>
  )}
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `PageNotFound` isn't a layout route component. In other words, it's not rendering an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their `element` content into.

## Solution

If I understand your post correctly you want:

1. Render `IndividualPlanning` exactly on path `"/planning"`
2. Render `IndividualPlanning` also on path `"/planning/individual"`
3. Render `PageNotFound` on any `"/planning/*"` sub-route that isn't already specifically handled.

Render the `"/planning"` route without an `element` prop so an `Outlet` component is rendered by default. Convert the index route to redirect to the `"/planning/individual"` route. Move the "catch-all" `PageNoutFound` route out of the `"/planning/*"` routes to handle any unhandled/unknown routes.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  {!isLogged() ? (
    <>
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={"/login"} />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />

      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />

      <Route path="planning">
        <Route index element={<Navigate to="individual" replace />} />
        <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
        <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
    </>
  )}
</Routes>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-v6-children-routes-not-displaying-correct-component]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for !! +1 for the explanations as well. Thank's!

Answer (score -1):

React Router v6, you should use the * wildcard instead of exact. Here's the updated code:

```
    import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function YourComponent() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="planning/*" element={<PageNotFound />} >
        <Route index element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
        <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
        <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using 
```
      <Route path="planning/*" element={<PageNotFound />} >
        <Route index element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
        <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
        <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
      </Route>
``` is acting just the same, when I visit /planning it displays correctly the not fuond page, but when I go to /planning/individual or /planning/team it keep displaying the not found page

Answer (score -1):

```
<Route exact path="*" element={<PageNotFound />}>
```

can you try to write it like this?

Comment: I already got this somewhere else in the core routes, but it doesn't display it when the route with path = "planning" is reached.
It looks like since the route exist, it doesn't enter the "*"

Comment: @Enzo if you have higher level routes you should post those in case they interecept the route before reaching this point.

Comment: I doubt its the case, but I edited the question if it can help

Comment: In v6 version it no longer uses nested routes and the exact attribute is no longer used. You can use index instead. Can you try this?
<Route path="planning" element={<Outlet />}>
  <Route index element={<PageNotFound />} />
  <Route path="individual" element={<IndividualPlanning />} />
  <Route path="team" element={<TeamPlanning />} />
</Route>