# Switch Router not working in React application

Tags: reactjs

Switch Router is not working in my React application. I installed `react-router-dom`:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

but it is still not working. I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 12:35-41
export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_useBlocker, unstable_usePrompt, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much info about the version of `react-router-dom` you installed, however I'm going to assume you installed the latest version which is 6.10.0. In that case, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69843676/17465266

tl;dr is that `Switch` was replaced with `Routes`. Take a look at the example here (from https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes):

```
import {
  Routes, // instead of "Switch"
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

// ...

<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route
      path="messages"
      element={<DashboardMessages />}
    />
    <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>
```