# eroor React please guide me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ERROR in ./src/App.js 39:41-47
export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_FetchersContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_ViewTransitionContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_usePrompt, unstable_useViewTransitionState, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useBlocker, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)

Comment: which is the react router dom version?

Comment: that wall of gibberish isn't helping

Comment: similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843615/switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom

Comment: Version 6 react-router-dom

Comment: Could you please provide the code you used?